# Is there a way to Login as another user in Chrome using selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with `C#` and I'm having problems as my web application is taking user credentials from AD(Active Directory), can we restrict this using selenium code for login as another user.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\SeleniumProfiles\Default");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://version");
```

Comment: It depends on how your application is authenticating client requests. If it's currently configured to only work with Windows Authentication, you can try impersonation and see if that works. If you can change the authentication mechanism to "Basic Authentication" (for automation only), that could be easier, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help @haim770. Do you have any code sample to change the authentication mechanism to "Basic Authentication" in C#